# Would adding a where clause be a good idea here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with some columns .. say A,B & C and a last column called DeletedDate. Its a nullable datetime.

I have added a unique constraint on A,B & C. Its worked fine until I discovered an issue. After adding a deleted date. I should be able to add a new records for same A,B & C values. But I cant because of the unique constraint.

I see two options here

1. Include the DeletedDate column in constraint
2. Add a where clause to the constraint saying `Where DeletedDate is not NULL`

My question: Which option is better & why?

Comment: You can't add a where clause to a constraint. That doesn't make any sense. What you are running into is one of the challenges of doing soft deletes.

Comment: Can you have many `A, B, C, <date>` but only one `A, B, C, NULL`?

Comment: @SeanLange True but you can add a where clause to an index - which then becomes filtered.

Comment: Or you rework the business logic - DeleteDate gets set to null instead of readding the item.

Comment: @Andrew Yes. That's True

Comment: @TomTom That not an option

Comment: What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: @TimSchmelter There is a different primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2: a unique constraint cannot have a `WHERE` clause. But you can use a **[filtered index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc280372.aspx)** instead:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_b_c_UQ_when_DeletedDate_is_null
ON TableName
  (a, b, c) 
WHERE DeletedDate IS NULL ;
```

---

Option 1: if you simply include the `DeletedDate` in the unique constraint, then there are 2 issues:

- a tiny, minor one is that if SQL-Server had implemented unique constraints as in the sql-Standard, that would allow to have 2 or more rows with same a,b,c combination and null deleted date, so 2 or more undeleted rows can coexist, which would not match the requirements. This is not an issue of course with current implementation. It might only become one, if SQL-Server decides in the future to change the implementation, so as to comply with the standard.
- a somewhat more important issue is that this way you would not allow to have 2 or more rows with same a,b,c combination and same exact deleted date. This is not a serious problem either in your case, because the `DeletedDate` is a `datetime` and not a `date`. It might only bring some difficulty if you try to delete several rows with the same statement/transaction.

Comment: I like this option too. But why do you think its better than option 1?

Comment: I dont think that's true. If I include the deleted date in the constraint. I will have all the unique combinations and deleted date will be null only ONCE. It cant exist more than once .. that will violate the constraint.

Comment: @BilalFazlani Oh yes, true. I always get confused by SQL-Server's non-standard implementation of unique indexes regarding nulls.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a computed column for the unique index. This returns a static value like `1` if `DeletedDate` is available and otherwise the negative counterpart of the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A] [int] NOT NULL,
    [B] [int] NOT NULL,
    [C] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DeletedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsDeleted]  AS (case when [DeletedDate] IS NULL then (1) else  -(1)*[ID] end),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Now you can create a unique index on A,B,C and IsDeleted.

Comment: This seems to a very different from the 2 options available to me. I would really appreciate If you could tell me which option is better and why from those 2 options ...

Comment: Thanks for the third option though :)

Answer (score 0):

Dates do not tend to be good choices for inclusion unique indexes/constraints, because they have a finite resolution and you aren't going to be guaranteed unique values all the time -- what if you need to add bulk delete functionality down the road that deletes ten things at once? They would all have the same deleted date.

Unfortunately, since the question is (appropriately) abstract to focus on the null issue, I don't know what the use case is for the constraint, so I can't recommend another approach. However, I would say "no" as an answer to the actual question, because the null issue is just going to be the first of many problems with a unique date value.